# slicing an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to slice an array after an item in it has been used but the code is not doing that:

```
vm.removeItem = function() {
  for(let i = 0; i < vm.array.length; i++) {
    if(vm.array[i].item === vm.item) {
      vm.array.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
};
```

Is there something I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Does this have to be tagged angularjs?

Comment: @CrescentFresh, doesnt havet, but I used it anyway thinking im a newbie in Angular and JS

Comment: What is vm? What item are you trying to slice off? The function takes no parameters, so I can only assume either the first or last element.  But if that was the case, there's no need for a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

A dummy code is being assumed. The item to be removed is stored in item.
After removeItem is invoked, its removed.

```js
var vm = {
  array: [{
    lp: 1
  }, {
    lp: 2
  }, {
    lp: 3
  }],
  item: 2
};

vm.removeItem = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < vm.array.length; i++) {
    if (vm.array[i].lp === vm.item) {
      vm.array.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
};

vm.removeItem();
console.log(vm.array);
```

Comment: @John Please check this code, is this what you were looking for? I tried to create a dummy code to make it workable.

Answer (score 0):

According to your existing code, it seems like your `vm` structure looks like that:

```
var vm = {
  item: 'ef',
  array: [ {item: 'ab'}, {item : 'cd'}, {item: 'ef'}, {item: 'gh'} ]
};
```

If you want to remove from `vm.array` the element whose `item` attribute is `vm.item`, you can do:

```
vm.array = vm.array.filter(function(e) { return e.item != vm.item; });
```

However, I *think* that your code should work as expected and do exactly the same thing. So, the problem might be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a duplicate of [Remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Anyways, you can always do something like this:

```
function remove(arr, item) {
  for(var i = arr.length; i--;) {
    if(arr[i] === item) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the usage:

```
// an array
var entries = [
    {name:'Tim'},
  {name:'John'}
];
// add an item to the array
var mark = {name:'Mark'};
entries.push(mark);

// you can see it's in the array now
entries.forEach(x => console.log(x.name));

// remove it from the array
remove(entries,mark );

// you can see it's not there now
entries.forEach(x => console.log(x.name));
```